# View animating from the incorrect position

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a cover view in my code. Essentially the cover slides up (closes) from off-screen to on-screen, and after the user presses a button the cover slides down (opens up) all the way off-screen.

My code to slide the cover view up the screen and into view is working perfectly. However, the code to slide the cover view down the screen and out of view is not working! The starting position for the cover sliding down is what seems to be incorrect. The cover slides down as expected, but starts far too high, such that the animation ends where it should start.

I've got a screen recording of the error in action (obviously slowed the animation down so you can see what I mean by the error). The cover sliding down should be sliding down from its original position where it slid up to. 
[Link to recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1PUw.jpg).

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong in my code?

```
func showScoresCover() {
    verticalDistance = ScoresCoverView.frame.size.height
    self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y += verticalDistance
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.5,
        delay: 0.25,
        options: .curveEaseOut,
        animations:
        { self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y -= self.verticalDistance},
        completion:
        { finished in
          print("Score cover closed.")
        })
}

func hideScoresCover() {
    verticalDistance = ScoresCoverView.frame.size.height
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.5,
        delay: 0.25,
        options: .curveEaseIn,
        animations:
        { self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y += self.verticalDistance},
        completion:
        { finished in
          print("Score cover opened.")
        })
}
```

## EDIT

hey @Nickolans thanks for your help on this issue. So... I have a bizarre update for you on this query. I implemented your code, and it works if I have a pre-programmed button which fires the showScoreCover and hideScoresCover. Turns out even my original code works, but again, only if I have a pre-programmed button which fires the show/hide functions.

However, I need to fire the function using a button where I programmatically reconfigure what the button does. How I've implemented this is through .addTarget and a number of selectors, and those selectors will differ based on where in the game the users are.

Anyway, this is what my code looks like:

```
self.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideScoresCover), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.startTeamB), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Originally I only used one .addTarget and included the hideScoresCover() in the startTeamB function. This was resulting in the original issue where the cover doesn't hide correctly (starts too high on the screen). So I split it up into the above two .addTargets, and that also results in the same issue. HOWEVER, if I comment out the entire .addTarget line above related to the startTeamB selector and leave the selector related to hideScoresCover, then the cover is shown and is hidden absolutely as I want to to be, the animation is perfect. This means the underlying code in hideScoresCover() is working fine, but that the issue is arising somehow in how hideScoresCover is being run when the continue button is pressed.

Do you have any idea why this would be? somehow that continueButton target is firing incorrectly whenever there are two addTargets, or when there is only one target but hideScoresCover() is included in startTeamB().

I'm stumped as to why this would be the case. startTeamB() is not a complex function at all, so shouldn't be interfering with hideScoresCover(). So this leads me only to conclude it must be the way the continueButton fires hideScoresCover() when its either a separate target in addition to startTeamB being a target, or when hideScoresCover() is included in startTeamB itself. Unusual that it does work correctly when the only .addTarget is a selector calling hidesScoresCover?

```
@objc func startTeamB() {
    self.UpdateTeam() //Just changes the team name
    self.TeamBTimer() //Starts a timer to countdown teamB's remaining time
    self.TeamAIndicator.isHidden = true //Just hides teamA image
    self.TeamBIndicator.isHidden = false //Just shows teamB image
    print("Hintify: ","-----Start Team B.")
}
```

Comment: It may be that you're adding to  the ScoresCoverView y position. If the function is run multiple times the y value will continuously change.

Comment: HI @Nickolans! Yeah that was what I thought could be the case because the starting position seems to be exactly out by 'verticalDistance'. But how do you animate the frame other than applying verticalDistance to frame.origin.y?

Comment: The animations only occur inside UIView.animate(), so take out "self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y += verticalDistance" and move it into your viewDidLoad that way it's not being set everytime you call the fuction.

Comment: @Nickolans, I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly... the animation is for the frame to move down the y-axis by verticalDistance is within the "animations: {}" closure of UIView.animate()... if I moved it to viewDidLoad, we wouldn't get any animation when running hideScoresCover()

Comment: Okay, I've edited my response! PS: If you have any further questions, make to open up a new question/thread and not to reuse the same one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took it into Xcode and set it up myself. I believe the issue may be how you're changing your Y value, instead of changing the origin change the view layers y position.

The following code works so you can just take it! Make sure to change the frame to whatever you need it to be when you first start.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Bool to keep track if view is open
var isOpen = false

var verticalDistance: CGFloat = 0
var ScoresCoverView = UIView()
var button = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    //Setup Score view
    ScoresCoverView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
    ScoresCoverView.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(ScoresCoverView)

    //Set vertical distance
    verticalDistance = ScoresCoverView.frame.height

    //TEST button to test view animations
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 500, width: 100, height: 100)
    button.backgroundColor = .purple
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hasBeenFired), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

//When button pressed
@objc func hasBeenFired() {
    if isOpen {
        self.hideScoresCover()
        self.isOpen = false
    } else {
        self.showScoresCover()
        self.isOpen = true
    }
}

//Show
func showScoresCover() {

    self.ScoresCoverView.isHidden = false

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.ScoresCoverView.layer.position.y -= self.verticalDistance
    }) { (finished) in
        print("Score cover closed.")
    }
}

//Hide
func hideScoresCover() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.ScoresCoverView.layer.position.y += self.verticalDistance
    }) { (finished) in
        self.ScoresCoverView.isHidden = true
        print("Score cover Opened.")
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

If you'd like to change the functionality of the button, make sure to remove the previous target before adding a new one.

For example, if you want to switch from show/hide *to* teamB ***remove*** show/hide and add teamB-- and vice versa.

When you first start, add your initial target:

```
self.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideScoresCover), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Switch to startTeamB:

```
self.continueButton.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideScoresCover), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.startTeamB), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Switch to hideScoreCover:

```
self.continueButton.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.startTeamB), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideScoresCover), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Hmmm... strangely enough, this doesn't fix the problem. still get the same issue

Comment: Okay, I updated the code in the answer! The code works. I think it's how you're changing your Y or it may be how you have your code laid out. Either way, the above code should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks mate! It seems to have worked. When I used your code as above, the blocks move as expected. When I move it to my code, the same error occurs, so I must have some kind of conflicting layout issues which are preventing the view sliding down as expected... I've gone and manually recreated my storyboard and created a new VC with the above and its worked. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: hey @Nickolans I've added an edit to my original question that I'm hoping you can answer. Your code works (as does my original code), but the way its being fired is what seems to be causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say one thing, maybe the `+=` is not necessary here.

```
func showScoresCover() {
verticalDistance = ScoresCoverView.frame.size.height
self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y += verticalDistance
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.5,
    delay: 0.25,
    options: .curveEaseOut,
    animations:
    { self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y -= self.verticalDistance},
    completion:
    { finished in
      print("Score cover closed.")
    })
}
```

should be

```
   `self.ScoresCoverView.frame.origin.y = verticalDistance`
```